# Updating TextView from another class using runOnUiThread

Tags: android

On my MainActivity.java file I have the following code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Context context;
    private static TextView tvStatus;


    //other irrelevant methods

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.context;
    }
    
    public void log(String message) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvStatus.append(message + "\n");
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

since the method can't be made static, how can I call the `log` method from different classes and/or threads?

Comment: i would not use static for context. it could lead to memory leaks

Comment: In addition to above I would not use Thread with Sleep, If function does not work properly within 300 ms, It may give crash.

Comment: `public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.context;
    }` If that is a member of your activity then why do you name it like that? Further it is an impossible function as beeing static you could call it without having an activity instance. So there would be no context then either.

Comment: This log function logging on a text view is not a good idea at all. If you want your logs on a text view then use a broadcast receiver in your activity.

Comment: `since the method can't be made static, ` Indeed. And there is a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your use case is but an easy way to approach this is using modern android development practices, for example, coroutines, live data, and view models. But if you still have a solid use case, you can do something like this (I would not recommend this in production application)

```
class LogCaller {
    private WeakReference<Activity> weakReference;

    public void setWeakReference(Activity activity) {
        weakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    public void clearReference() {
        if (weakReference != null) {
            weakReference.clear();
        }
    }


    void doSomething() {
        if (weakReference != null) {
            Activity activity = weakReference.get();
            if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing() && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
                ((MainActivity) activity).log();
            }
        }
    }
}
```